# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, arcpy

I realize this is a common topic for posts here, however, I can't seem to find one example that really helped me fix the problem. I'm trying to run a script that will add two new fields (x and y coords) to a shapefile then populate those fields with X and Y coords using the code block. This is for AcrGIS 10.2.2, but I don't think the problem is a ArcGIS problem. Script below:

```
# Add new fields for "New_X" and "New_Y" for new points to be added
# Calculate values for those new fields based on distance along line
import arcpy, arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"G:\Geocomputation_Project\Section_C\Model_Shapes"
env.overwriteOutput = True

# Set local Variables
in_table = 'Points.shp'
field_x = 'New_X'
field_y = 'New_Y'
expression = "getXY(!Shape!, !ITEMID!, !CHAINAGE!)"
code_block_x = """def getXY (point, id, d2add):
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("G:\Geocomputation_Project\Section_C\Model_Shapes\Geocomputation_Project.mxd")
lyr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"LINES")[0]
q='"ITEMID"=%s%s%s' %(r"'",id,"'")
pNew = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,"Shape@",q)as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        line=row[0];break
        pointPos=line.measureOnLine(point)+d2add
        pNew+=line.positionAlongLine(pointPos).firstPoint
pNew.X"""
code_block_y = """def getXY (point, id, d2add):
mxd =  arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("G:\Geocomputation_Project\Section_C\Model_Shapes\Geocomputation_Project.mxd")
lyr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"LINES")[0]
q='"ITEMID"=%s%s%s' %(r"'",id,"'")
pNew = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,"Shape@",q)as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        line=row[0];break
        pointPos=line.measureOnLine(point)+d2add
        pNew+=line.positionAlongLine(pointPos).firstPoint
pNew.Y"""

# Execute AddField for each new X and Y coord
arcpy.AddField_management(in_table, field_x, "Double")
arcpy.AddField_management(in_table, field_y, "Double")

# Execute CalculateField to each new X and Y field
arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table, field_x, expression,  "PYTHON_9.3", code_block_x)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table, field_y, expression, "PYTHON_9.3", code_block_y)
```

I keep getting AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'X'.

Comment: Make your mind up - is it `int` or `list` in the error message?

Comment: Why do you have `line=row[0];break`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the error in the title is correct, and not the one in the post body, here's your problem:

```
pNew = 0
# ...
pNew.Y
```

It should be pretty obvious that's not going to work

Comment: well the whole reason I added `pnew = 0` is to avoid a "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pNew_Y' referenced before assignment"

Comment: That appears twice in the code, one for the X and one for the Y.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now, there seemed to be more just a syntax/indentation error. Also needed to "return" the pNew variable. See below working script below:

```
code_block_x = """def getXY (point, id, d2add):
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("G:\Geocomputation_Project\Section_C\Model_Shapes\Geocomputation_Project.mxd")
lyr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"LINES")[0]
q='"ITEMID"=%s%s%s' %(r"'",id,"'")
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,"Shape@",q)as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        line=row[0];break
pointPos=line.measureOnLine(point)+d2add
pNew=line.positionAlongLine(pointPos).firstPoint
return pNew.X"""
```

and

```
code_block_y = """def getXY (point, id, d2add):
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("G:\Geocomputation_Project\Section_C\Model_Shapes\Geocomputation_Project.mxd")
lyr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"LINES")[0]
q='"ITEMID"=%s%s%s' %(r"'",id,"'")
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,"Shape@",q)as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        line=row[0];break
pointPos=line.measureOnLine(point)+d2add
pNew=line.positionAlongLine(pointPos).firstPoint
return pNew.Y"""
```